# MSMQ and Windows Service not receiving messages even though queue has messages

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq

Win 7, MSMQ, Windows Service.

I check the queue in computer management and messages there.

When i run the service by calling it from Main ie a hack to allow debugging it
works fine.

But When I run the windows service as a service starting from comp management
the queue is not receving any messages.

Any ideas, could it be permissions??

Comment: it could be a permission issue, make sure that the user account which you are running the service has a receive permission in the queue to which you are sending the message.

Comment: ok how do I check that please?

Comment: Fixed it was permissions of the queue.